# Unexplained R failure: Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r

I am trying to specify the size of a plot dynamically in RMarkdown. Because it is a facetted plot with a dynamic number of plots, the aspect ratio needs to change.

I'm using this code:

````
...
jobs_levels <- 9

```

#### Figure 3.1.1. Effect of Inidivdual Interventions in Living Rooms

```{r figure_3_3_1, fig.height=jobs_levels}

jobs_levels
print(figure_3_3_1)

```
````

For the sake of simplicity, I've hard coded the jobs_levels (the number of levels in the facetting factor). As you can see, I set the value very clearly,and then use it in the very next code chuck. I can see the value clear as day in the environment. It is 9. But I get this:

````
Error in eval(ele) : object 'jobs_levels' not found
> ```{r figure_3_3_1, fig.height=jobs_levels}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
````

When I run this in batch mode, it crashes. Any idea what is going on with this?

I even put in the extra lines:

```
jobs_levels
```

to debug. EAch time I run one of those lines with cotrl enter, it evaluates right, but I see the error message again too...

Comment: based on your post, you are not defining `jobs_levels` in an r code chunk

Comment: Please provide a self-contained minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can copy/paste into R to test with. Are you saying `jobs_levels <- 9` in in the Rmd document? What exactly do you mean when you say you run it in "bactch mode"

Comment: How is `figure_3_3_1` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message makes it look as though you are trying to evaluate the chunk header as R code.  You had

````
```{r figure_3_3_1, fig.height=jobs_levels}
````

The first two backticks would be parsed as a zero length variable name, as the error message states.

You can't run R Markdown code as R code, you need to use `rmarkdown::render` or a related function to run it.

Comment: This *does* explain the error. So this was the combination of R's non-existent error reporting, a different unrelated error and the confusion between running the chunk and rendering it.

Comment: "Non-existent"?  But it was the R error message that made the problem clear.

Comment: A metaphor: In literal terms, insufficient.